# Unable to display fetched data in react native firebase using this.state.data.map()

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I have been battling with the display of database item on my page using this.state.noteArray.map(val, key). I intend to display each value with a delete button to remove it from the page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            noteArray: [],
            noteText: '',
        };
        this.addNote = this.addNote.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){

        firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child("todo")
        .once("value", snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            if (snapshot.val()){
                const initNoteArray = [];
                Object
                .keys(data)
                .forEach(noteText => initNoteArray.push(data[noteText]));
                this.setState({
                    noteArray: initNoteArray
                });
            }
        });
        firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child("todo")
        .on("child_added", snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            if (data){
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    noteArray: [data, ...prevState.noteArray]
                }))
                console.log(this.state.noteArray);
            }
        })
    }
    addNote(){
        // firebase function here to send to the database
        if (!this.state.noteText) return;
        var d = new Date();
        const newNote =  firebase.database().ref()
                              .child("todo")
                              .push ({
                                'date':d.getFullYear()+
                                "/"+(d.getMonth()+1) +
                                "/"+ d.getDate(),
                                'note': this.state.noteText
                            });
        newNote.set(this.state.noteText, () => this.setState({noteText: ''}))
    }
    render() {
        let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
            return
                    (<View key={key} keyval={key} val={val} style={styles.note}>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.state.val.date}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.state.val.note}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.state.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                    <Text deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)} style={styles.noteDeleteText}>D</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>)
        });
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo App</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                 {notes}
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <TextInput 
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholder='>note'
                        onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                        value={this.state.noteText}
                        placeholderTextColor='white'
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                    </TextInput>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addNote } style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    deleteNote(key){
        this.state.noteArray.splice(key, 1);
        this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
    }
}
```

There is no warning or error, but it is not displaying anything. I will appreciate if there is any help and inline comment to understand the process for the next time, I am a newbie, trying to master the code for future similar projects. All I care to know is the basic understanding of the CRUD and search using React native firebase. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you need a proper way to display your data. Since noteArray is an array, there's nothing easier than a FlatList, which is scrollable by itself.
So, in your render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.noteArray} // Here is where you pass your array of data
              renderItem={this.renderItem} // Here is how to display each item of your data array
              ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
              ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Where:

```
renderHeader = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo App</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

renderFooter = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder='>note'
                    onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                    value={this.state.noteText}
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                </TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addNote } style={styles.addButton}>
                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <View key={index} style={styles.note}>
            <Text style={styles.noteText}>{item.date}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.noteText}>{item.note}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.state.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                <Text deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(index)} style={styles.noteDeleteText}>D</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, it is displaying error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:687)
    in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:852)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1062)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:663)
    in FlatList (at Main.js:80)

Comment: Yeah, it displays but the textinput is not enabled to write a new item, and the delete function isn't working. There is a warning also: VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor. Thanks

Comment: Uhm, i didn't touch that portion of code, but I'll take a look

Comment: Ok, thanks I will be expecting. Is there any tutorial u can recommend

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have much more time. I noticed the delete function is uncorrect at all, but TextInput seems valid. I suggest you to read the official documentation, it's good and full of examples that can help you. Good luck! And I'd be grateful if you would consider checked this answer (since it is in my opinion) or maybe just a little upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support. I have reviewed my code and it is working perfectly as I want. I will love to post it here in case someone else needs to work or learn about it. I used array.map() function to iterate over the items.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import Note from './Note';
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            noteArray: [],
            noteText: '',
        };
        this.addNote = this.addNote.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){

        firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child("todo")
        .once("value", snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            if (snapshot.val()){
                const initNoteArray = [];
                Object
                .keys(data)
                .forEach(noteText => initNoteArray.push(data[noteText]));
                this.setState({
                    noteArray: initNoteArray
                });
            }
        });
        firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child("todo")
        .on("child_added", snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            if (data){
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    noteArray: [data, ...prevState.noteArray]
                }))
                console.log(this.state.noteArray);
            }
        })
    }
    addNote(){
        // firebase function here to send to the database
        if (!this.state.noteText) return;
        var d = new Date();
        const newNote =  firebase.database().ref()
                              .child("todo")
                              .push ();
        newNote.set({
            'date':d.getFullYear()+
            "/"+(d.getMonth()+1) +
            "/"+ d.getDate(),
            'note': this.state.noteText
        });
        this.setState({noteText:''});
    }

    render() {
        let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
            return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
                    deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)}/>
        });
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo App</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                 {notes}
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <TextInput 
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholder='>note'
                        onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                        value={this.state.noteText}
                        placeholderTextColor='white'
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                    </TextInput>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addNote } style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }


    deleteNote(key){
        this.state.noteArray.splice(key, 1);
        this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
    }

}
```

I have another .js component named Note.js for display template. This was included in the Main.js and was reference just after the render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
export default class Note extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.note}>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                    <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>D</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```